# 3d engine with telnet access

Tags: networking, scripting, 3d-engine

Does anyone know of a open source 3d engine which can be operated via telnet?

What I'm looking for is scripting via a socket connection. To allow for world creation and/or camera movement.

Does anybody know of any that has this built in or very, very easy to add as a plugin or script?

The platform is not crucial.

Comment: Telnet isn't a 3D protocol. Why do you want to do this? What's at the other end of the socket connection? Something you plan to write, or are you hoping that there's some kind of preexisting service that lets you do this?

Comment: For ease of use and rapid prototyping. I'm planning to write the client side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doesn't look like it. I'll just do it myself.

Answer (score 1):

You can [script Blender using Python](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:2.5/Py/API/Intro); probably this allows to open a listening socket connection, too. It also has a 'game engine' mode just for rapid prototyping.

Comment: thanks for that. I'm downloading blender again and I'll try to check it out. Just wish it was easier to work with.

Comment: @zaf: Blender _is_ easy to work with once you've spent a week learning and cursing. It's a bit non-obvious at first glance — but so are many other good things, like git or tex.

Answer (score 0):

It shouldn't take you more than 10 minutes to add this to an engine, so it really doesn't matter which one you go for.